# jQuery .load() function (not loading files completely)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been struggling with query for some time. I have a CMS that I want to use on my site, but I cant use PHP includes so I decided to use jquery. I have made all the necessary includes and when I open the webpage it doesn't load all the files... Rarely does load() function load every file. Any ideas to solve the problem or alternatives? thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // find element with ID of "target" and put file contents into it
        $('#welcome-container').load('admin/data/blocks/Slider/Text.html');
        $('#slides').load('admin/data/blocks/Slider/Imagini.html');
        $('#acasa-continut').load('admin/data/blocks/Acasa/Continut.html');
        $('#sidebar').load('admin/data/blocks/Sidebar/Continut.html');
        $('#sidebar-v1').load('admin/data/blocks/Sidebar/Video-1.html');
        $('#sidebar-v2').load('admin/data/blocks/Sidebar/Video-2.html');
        $('#principii').load('admin/data/blocks/Despre/Principii.html');
        $('#echipa').load('admin/data/blocks/Despre/Echipa.html');
        $('#echipament').load('admin/data/blocks/Despre/Echipament.html');
        $('#contact-t').load('admin/data/blocks/Contact/Contact.html');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the requests in the network pane in the developer tools of whatever browser you use?

Comment: @lanzz I guess it would make sense to ask questions before suggesting something like `$.ajax`

Comment: One could also use the second argument to `load`, which is a function called after the load completes. Helpful for diagnosing errors. See http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Does it load some files? Or none? You say "Rarely does load() function load every file"

Comment: Yes, it loads some files(most of them), but not all... I have checked with developer tools and i get 500 Internal Server Error